# Buffered read from disk

Tags: disk, buffered

I want to read a file in a programming language (i.e. java). Usually the method signature is

```
   byte[] readBytes(int numberOfBytes) .
```

The number of bytes should be a multiple of the block size of the format used by the Operating system (i.e. Windows 4096)? Which is a number of bytes I should specify to get really good performance? What is the difference between the BufferedInputStream, and a normal InputStream?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about that (anymore, fortunately!). It's up to the OS to manage correctly and transparent to application programmer.